# Centos 6 with WHM Server configuration for Akeneo

Tags: php, apache, centos6, whm, akeneo

I am trying to configure Akeneo With WHM in Centos 6 Apache 2 server.
I am following this tutorials [enter link description here](https://docs.akeneo.com/2.0/install_pim/manual/system_requirements/system_install_ubuntu_1604.html)

I configured this in ubuntu machine I got no error. The issue I found is with server and php.

When I launch my site I get this following error.

```
No input file specified.
```

My httd.conf file below:

```
<VirtualHost my-ip:80>
  ServerName my-domain.co
    ServerAlias mail.domain-group.co www.abs-group.co
  DocumentRoot /home/user/public_html/pim-community-standard/web/
 <Directory "/home/user/public_html/pim-community-standard/web">
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted

        Options -MultiViews
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
   </Directory>
 <Directory /home/user/public_html/pim-community-standard>
        Options FollowSymlinks
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/user/public_html/pim-community-standard/web/bundles>
        RewriteEngine Off
    </Directory>

    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/var/run/php-fpm/897e2bef0970b20f1bbeeae9d7c0de8ba9c47453.sock|fcgi://my-domain.co/"
    </FilesMatch>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@user-group.co
  UseCanonicalName Off

</VirtualHost>
```

I get the following error in my apache error log.

```
AH01071: Got error 'Unable to open primary script: /home/user/public_html/pim-community-standard/web/app.php (No such file or directory)\n'
```

I am struggling with this error for past 2days. Please help me.